# Android: How to reduce loading times of a webview inside a listview?

Tags: android, performance

I have a ListView and the first view in the list view is a WebView. The other views are text-based. When I load the app, it takes a few seconds for the webview to load. This was expected. However, after I scroll down, so that the list view is off the screen and then scroll back up to the webview, it takes another few seconds to load. Is there a way to save the contents of the webview and restore them upon seeing the view again? better yet, since the webview is actually showing a slideshow, is there a way that the webview can be running while scrolled off screen?

Comment: I have the same problem. did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is actually a feature of the ListView designed to improve overall performance of the scrolling. As far as I know, there is not an easy way to disable this behavior. Perhaps, if you think performance is acceptable, you could try using a ScrollView in place of a ListView here.